# List of Relational Tuples Into Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, tuples

I have the following list of tuples:

```py
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (4, 6)]
```

I want the following nested Dictionary:

```py
{
   "0":{
      "1":{
         "2":{},
         "3":{
            "4":{
               "6":{}
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "5":{
      "6":{}
   }
}
```

What approach should be followed to convert the above list of tuples into a nested dictionary as illustrated above?
Basically, I wanted to store the following graph nodes and their relationship as a dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want that?  That's not a tree or a graph.  Why would you want elements to be dupicated?

Comment: It looks like it's some kind of pathing variant. Where there's a path from 0->1->2, 0->1->3->4->6, 5->6, etc.

Comment: @HenryEcker, you are right. I have edited the original question with the graph image showing these paths as well.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if there was `(6, 7)` in the list? Would this be duplicated for every "6"?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, it should be duplicated for every "6".

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy with a defaultdict. Just need some extra logic to delete any nodes that aren't top level/ parents in the graph.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (4, 6)]

result = defaultdict(dict)
children = set()

for parent, child in data:
    result[parent][child] = result[child]
    children.add(child)

for child in children:
    del result[child]

print(dict(result))
```

```
{0: {1: {2: {}, 3: {4: {6: {}}}}}, 5: {6: {}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use recursion:

```
data = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6), (4, 6)]
def to_dict(n):
  return {b:to_dict(b) for a, b in data if a == n}

r = {a:to_dict(a) for a, _ in data if not any(b == a for _, b in data)}
```

Output:

```
{0: {1: {2: {}, 3: {4: {6: {}}}}}, 5: {6: {}}}
```